# How to open external links in a WebView Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, webview, swiftui, uiwebview

I've a question about opening external links in my webView of SwiftUI. The web page loaded properly, but I can't open external links from this website (for example: Facebook, YouTube, Mail, Phone etc). Please, who can give me a help on this one?

I added the code below:

You can call an url, like ShowWebpage("https://www.wordpress.com"), in the ContentView.

```
  struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let request: URLRequest
    private var webView: WKWebView?
    
    init(request: URLRequest) {
            self.webView = WKWebView()
            self.request = request
            self.webView?.configuration.defaultWebpagePreferences.allowsContentJavaScript = true
       
        }
  
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        return webView!
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.load(request)
    }
}

struct ShowWebpage : View {
    //get URL Page
    var urlpage: String

    var body: some View {
        let webview = WebView(request: URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlpage)!))

        VStack{
            //Load URL page
            webview
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You already had the same topic some 36 hours, didn't you?  What's new?

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. Your code works as expected.